# How to sum up shell script args to one string

Tags: shell

i am writing a quick gitpush.sh file.

```
git add -u
git commit -m 'quick update: '$1
git push origin master
echo $1
```

when run it i want to add a custom message to it. so instead of writing:

```
sh gitpush.sh a_commit_for_lala_land
```

which is considered `$1`

i want to write

```
sh gitpush.sh a commit for lala land
```

without the underscores. how to i modify `$1` to sum up multiple arguments with a space in between each argument to form a sentence?

**EDIT**
I know this might not be proper git usage. but i only need it for an insignificant project i am working on alone (no branches etc).

Comment: What is so terrible about using quotes? `sh gitpush.sh "a commit for lala land"`?

Comment: Your script should be quoting `$1` in both cases anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use quotes properly:

```
git add -u
git commit -m "quick update: $1"
git push origin master
echo "$1"
```

Then when you call the script:

```
sh gitpush.sh "a commit for lala land"
```

If you really object to using quotes, have the script prompt you for the message instead of passing it as multiple arguments:

```
printf 'Commit message: ' >&2
IFS= read -r msg
git add -u
git commit -m "quick update: $msg"
git push origin master
echo "$msg"
```

Comment: @zwer answer made sure i don't need to add any quotes (i am not that lazy but it covers my current need). Thank you for the response though.

Comment: Just don't include any asterisks in your commit message. `sh gitpush.sh add an * to a comment` isn't going to do what you want. Really, it's better to do things the *right* way than to assume you are never going to get bitten by doing it the wrong way.

Comment: @GeorgePamfilis Without quoting, you wouldn't be able to say, e.g., `I'm just committing a day's worth of work`.

Comment: @Kusalananda i just tried your message and it stripped away the '. it showed up as `   0922bef..64b7011  master -> master
'Im just committing a days worth of work'` It's fine. ill keep it in mind

Comment: @GeorgePamfilis That's his point. You would have to escape the single quotes somehow if you wanted them as part of the commit message, or else the shell removes them before the string is ever passed to your script.

Comment: @GeorgePamfilis I should have had you try `I'm committing this now`... with a single single quote.  The quoting _is necessary_.

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate all the arguments using `$*`, e.g.:

```
git commit -m "$*"
```

NOTE: It will use the value of `$IFS` as a separator while concatenating - if it's defined as something other than a space you can temporary re-define it before calling `$*`.

Comment: The single quotes don't serve any purpose here, other than adding them to the commit message itself.

Comment: @chepner - True, I forgot to remove them from the OPs original line. Cleaned up.